# How can I identify an emoji in scala?

Tags: regex, string, scala, twitter, emoji

I am processing tweets from the Twitter Api, and a lot of the tweets have emojis. I'm trying to keep track of the most used emojis, but I'm having trouble actually identifying them.

I'm using: https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data to identify emojis.

I have no idea how to figure out if a string contains an emoji or not. I have tried using regex with the emoji-data 'unified' field, I have tried just checking if the string contains that field. I'm really just not sure how to check for emojis.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
val pattern = new Regex("(${a.unified})")
(pattern findAllIn text).mkString(",")
```

This is what I have tried using regex. This doesn't find any emojis. I have also tried adding a \u before the unified fields from the emoji-data, but that doesn't help.

Comment: " I have tried using regex with the emoji-data 'unified' field" — show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following Regex to find emoji characters (and other characters outside the Unicode lingual plane):

`[^\u0000-\uFFFF]`

For example, we use the following code to filter out emojis from strings:

`"some string".replaceAll("[^\u0000-\uFFFF]", "");`

Hope that helps.

Comment: That regexp filters out symbols of all non-latinic alphabets, not emojis only. Just try it with cyrilic, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is close to working. To extract the emojis from `text` try:

```
"""\p{block=Emoticons}""".r.findAllIn(text).mkString
```

For example:

```
scala> val text = "Use regex and now you have two problems  "
scala> """\p{block=Emoticons}""".r.findAllIn(text).mkString
res0: String =
```

Comment: Unfortunately it fails on complicated emojies, i. e. ‍‍ or just 

Comment: @ValeryRyaboshapko add some additional blocks to the regex: 
`"""[\p{block=Emoticons}\p{block=Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs}\p{block=Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs}]""".r.findAllIn("‍‍ or just ").mkString`
returns  (unfortunately does not give the family emoji)

Comment: @darrenmc  im getting an error saying program can't identify Supplemental and Pictographs. Do I need to import any library to add them to my regex?

Comment: @tharindu you do not any additional imports as this is built into the Java standard library. You do need to be on at java 10 or greater for "Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs" to be supported.