# Add multiple emojis present in a sentence into an array using scala

Tags: scala, emoji

Im trying to implement a lexicon where you can categorize emojis into different categories. For this emojis can be input in the form of a string.

```
val inputText = "I am happy today ".
```

How can i put these three emojis into an array as three elements using scala?
eg: `val ArrayEmoji = [, , ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify an emoji in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726037/how-can-i-identify-an-emoji-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a regex of emoticons (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53464865/14165730)) and convert to array of strings:

```
val inputText = "I am happy today "

val ArrayEmoji = raw"\p{block=Emoticons}".r.findAllIn(inputText).toArray
// ArrayEmoji: Array[String] = Array(, , )
```

Comment: Im getting an errr from IDE. but project complies correctly. error is "property escape sequences are not supported in this regex dialect"

Comment: @tharindu might be [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-17098). Try edited code?

Comment: still there is an error at \p section. but code works fine